# How to display Khmer text correctly in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unicode, unity-webgl

I have some text in Khmer language: "ចូលប្រើប្រាស់"

When I put that text in a UI Text component and using a [Khmer Unicode font](https://www.sbbic.org/2014/06/25/download-all-khmer-unicode-fonts/) (e.g: Content-Regular.ttf), Unity Editor displays like this image:

[image: Khmer text displayed incorrectly]

Is there any way to make Unity Editor and WebGL build display Khmer language properly?

Answer (score 1):

You should use TextMesh pro to create a font atlas, and then you can display any type of text and language as you want in any build.

Here is the link:

[Text Mesh Pro in Asset Store](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/beta-projects/textmesh-pro-84126)

Additionally, you should use **Content-Regular.ttf** as reference to create the font atlas.